# What does "novit in tali" mean?

Tags: contemporary-latin, latin-to-english-translation

I'm reading Arcadius Avellanus's translation of fairy tales (he was the last known native speaker of Latin), and I've come across this sentence:

> Regia Filia jocum dignata mittit ancillam cum lucerna, quam et magus erga novam perlibenter emutavit, quod satis novit in tali tantaque Aladdini palatio haud duas lucernas antiquas reperiri posse.

There are two things in the sentence that escape me. The first is that *et*, which context makes clear isn't the first or second of a pair. What does it mean here?

The second thing I'm having trouble with is *novit in tali*, which I can't make heads or tails of, whether the subject is *Regis Filia* or *magus*. Is *in tali tantaque* an idiom? It was indeed printed as *tantaque*, not *tantoque*, in the original from 1918.

Any thoughts about either of these things?

Comment: As for *et*, I'd take it as "also": "which the mage, too, ..."

Comment: Tali e tanti is idiomatic Italian so "tali tantaque" sounds as the natural latin basis for it to my  ears.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am using [this edition of the *Fabulae Divales*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JfI_TJo2Z_YC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false) as a basis for my below answer.

### *quam et*

In general, Latin prefers to link clauses that would often be independent in English: *propter quod*, *quam ob rem*, *qua ratione* are examples of causal linking.

Using the relative pronoun with *et* (or, even more commonly, *autem* or *enim*) has many precedents: it links two otherwise separate clauses.

> In eo perpetua canalis, **in quam et** cibus imponitur iis et immittitur aqua ([Varro, *De Agri Cultura*, III.11](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/varro.rr3.html))
>
> There is a perpetual channel in it, **and in it [=this channel]** food is placed for them and water is allowed in.

### *in tali tantaque*

This phrase is fairly common and means something like "of such a great kind". At least in my own head, I see it as a kind of [*hendiadys*](https://mcl.as.uky.edu/glossary-rhetorical-terms#20) ("use of two words connected by a conjunction, instead of subordinating one to the other, to express a single complex idea").

Here is one classical example of its usage:

> atque hoc non solum in te, **tali et tanto viro**, satis habebit ([*Letters to Atticus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0008%3Abook%3D9))

*tantaque* throws me for a bit of a loop, but I am confident that it is a typo. The only feminine words it could agree with in context are *ancilla* and *lucerna*, but neither works: *tanta ancilla* is rather mean, and there is no way to make *tanta lucerna* work with the rest of the sentence.

I read through the (otherwise delightful) Latin of the tale and noticed some other small errors such as:

- pg. 9: *qaum* instead of *quum* (= *cum*)
- pg. 12: *nolli timere* instead of *noli timere*

So, in the absence of better suggestions, I am willing to chalk this up to bad copy-editing or type-setting.

My proposed full translation (keeping the narrative present tense):

> *Regia Filia jocum dignata mittit ancillam cum lucerna, quam et magus erga novam perlibenter emutavit, quod satis novit in tali tantaque Aladdini palatio haud duas lucernas antiquas reperiri posse.*
>
> The Princess, consenting to the joke, sends her handmaid with the lamp, and the magician gladly exchanged it for a new one, for he knows well enough that two old lamps can hardly be found in such a great palace as Aladdin's.

Comment: Thank you so much—this answers my questions completely! I'm good with things like *enim* and *autem*, but I didn't realize that *et* could also be used postpositively—that was the missing piece there for me. As for the rest—erga tale tantumque responsum, quid multa? :)

Comment: On second thought--perhaps my example from Varro isn't good, since it is probably an *et...et* construction...

Comment: Hmm. I'll keep an eye out for examples, but if you come across any in the meantime, I'd love it if you could add them (and maybe ping me in a comment so I know to look).

Comment: @JoelDerfner *Et* can (I believe) be used postpositively in verse, but that's not that case here -- it's going with *magus*.

Comment: @TKR, usually *et* in this case would mean something like *even*, but if you read the passage in context that doesn't make much sense. What is your suggested reading?

Comment: @brianpck In this case I think it's not "even" but just "also": "which the magician, too..." I don't see another available reading -- certainly not postpositive because *et quam* wouldn't make any sense here.

Comment: My guess, after some consideration, is that *et* as "too" means that, just as the princess thought it a good idea to trade the lamps, the sorcerer **too** was happy to trade them.

Comment: Must by my ear, but I definitely read it as postpositive: "quam et magus" = "et magus hanc" for me...

Comment: @brianpck *Quam magus* by itself is equivalent to *et magus hanc*, so the *et* must be doing something else.